# How do I calculate percentage of rating?

Tags: average, percentages

I've average rating which is calculated by `Mean` formula. Now I want to calculate its percentage. I've following details:

1. The calculated average rating (`(sum(rating)/totalGivenRatings)`)
2. The total number of given ratings (`totalGivenRatings`)

e.g. I've average 2.23 and total number of given ratings are 3

Please help me, I'm newbie in maths.

**Edit 1**

I've tried following:

`(averageRating/totalGivenRatings)*100`

but is it fine?

Comment: Percentage of what?  Percentage of the total points available?  Percentile ranking compared to others?  If you define what you are looking for, the calculation will probably be obvious.

Comment: Percentage for just showing how much percentage of that rating are given. e.g. If average rating is 2.3 and total given rating are 3 then percentage of average rating. I've tried following: `(averageRating/totalRating)*100` but I've doubt about this

Comment: Why would you divide by the number of ratings?  How are totalGivenRatings and totalRating related?  It would be more normal to divide by the highest possible rating, but if the lowest is $1$ not $0$ you will  give a positive percentage to the lowest possible rating.

Comment: Actually its my mistake, the `totalRating` and `totalGivenRating` are same. It is the number of users who rated the product. And average rating is calculated as following : `sum(ratingByUser)/totalGivenRating`

Comment: Isn't averageRating already the sum of ratings divided by the number of ratings?  You should probably be dividing by the maximum rating, but note my earlier comment on the lowest being $1$, which is common.  What is the purpose of the calculation?  Is it just to have a number to display, or will you use it in a way that averageRating cannot be used for?

Comment: @RossMillikan, Yes, I've calculated average rating as stated you. The purpose of calculation is just to display percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from a friend. Followings are steps:

1. Get the sum of rating by following : `totalGivenRatings*MaxRating=sum(rating)`. e.g. `3*5=15` (Max rating is 5)
2. Get the total ratings from user by following : `averageRating*totalGivenRatings=totalRating` e.g. `2.23*3=6.99`
3. Get average by following : `(totalRating/sum(rating))*100` e.g. `6.99/15*100=46.6`

Thanks @RossMillikan for help and thanks to that friend also.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have an average rating, one way that makes sense is to show the percentage of the way up the range. You would calculate that by (average rating-minimum rating)/(max rating - min rating).  If the average is $2.23$ on a scale of $1$ to $5$, it would be $\frac {2.23-1}{5-1}=0.3075=30.75\%$.  Many people would just do average rating/max rating, but in our example that would give $20\%$ to a $1$ rating, the worst possible.  If you look at your calculation this will happen.